# How do you make flask execute a function via the app.run command?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have been trying to follow the tutorials to get flask apps to run on Heroku, like this one: https://dev.to/emcain/how-to-set-up-a-twitter-bot-with-python-and-heroku-1n39.

They all tell you to put this in your code in a file `server.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

And then run the app via the following command:

```
python3 server.py
```

But the tutorials don't explain how to connect the actual function you want to run using the app. In my case, I have a File `testbot.py` that has the function `test(arg1)` that contains the code I want to execute:

```
def test(arg1):
  while(1):
    #do stuff with arg1 on twitter
```

I want to do something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from testbot import test
from threading import Thread

app = Flask(__name__)
app.addfunction(test(arg1='hardcodedparameter'))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

So that when the app runs my `test()` function executes with the argument. Right now my server is starting, but nothing is happening.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

*Edit: I got it working with the solution, so my `server.py` now looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from testbot import test 

def main_process():
    test("hardcodeparam")

app = Flask(__name__)
Thread(target=main_process).start()
app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

And now `test` runs as expected.

Comment: How does "do stuff with arg1 on twitter" relate to the web service you want to run? What should cause "do stuff..." happen? Should that happen synchronously (probably not) or asynchronously (more likely)? A web server responds to HTTP requests. Try thinking about your application from that perspective.

Comment: Great! Does it working with multithreaded application and be called from one thread (Initial main thread) only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `app.run`, register the function with a path, e.g.

```
@app.route('/')
def test():  # no argument
    ... do one iteration
    return 'ok'
```

Then visiting the URL will trigger the function. Sites such as https://cron-job.org/ can automate that visiting on a regular basis for free, as suggested [here](https://www.naresh.se/2017/09/19/automate-twitter-bot/).

If the regular intervals aren't good enough, then you could try:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():  # no argument
    return 'ok'

def test():
    while True:
         # do stuff

from threading import Thread
Thread(target=test).start()

app.run(...)
```

You will probably still need to have a job regularly visiting the URL so that Heroku sees that the server is alive and in use.

Comment: Yes this worked, and I did not need the `app.route function`. ! I'll admit, I am not sure if this is best practice, but I can now run my bot from my Heroku server. Thanks!

Comment: According to https://www.naresh.se/2017/09/19/automate-twitter-bot/ "The only limitation is that your app will be killed if not accessed within 30 minutes". I've never done this myself so I can't confirm, but be aware of this possibility, hence the routing of at least one path.

Comment: Good looking out, I'll watch for that. Thanks!